# How to create a non executable jar in gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am a beginner in gradle , I wanted to know is there a way to create a non executable jar using gradle task.

currently I have generated the jar using ant

```
<target name="build-jar">
        <echo message="Creating jar"/>
         <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
         <jar destfile="${build}/lib/decouple-entity.jar"
         basedir="C:/ProjectRelated/Decouple/consumer/bin/main/com/el/export"
        includes="entity/** model/**"
        />  
</target>
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Just don't use a `public static void main(String[] args) {...}`-method within your jar.

Comment: What do mean by non-executable? That `java -jar decouple-entity.jar` will not run? Usually one has to define the main-class for that to be able to run.

Comment: Hi @Scratte I am trrying to build a dependecy jar which is containing pojo classess and will be used by other projects, I do not have main method, I want to find out a way to create the jar from gradle , I do not want to run the jar.

Comment: @paldin I have a spring boot application out of which I want to take only a few folders and create a new jar

Comment: As far as I know just don't include a `manifest.attributes 'Main-Class' : ...` in your build.gradle file. It would be helpful if you could post your current build.gradle file.